# How to download and install JMeter using PowerShell task in Azure DevOps?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, jmeter, performance-testing, taurus

In the Azure DevOps pipeline I am doing POC on instead of downloading the JMeter extension from Marketplace, I am trying to download it using PowerShell/Command line task.

I am not getting the exact command or approach that I can use to download Jmeterpowe using PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.1) cmdlet

- To download JMeter:

  ```
   Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.4.1.zip -OutFile c:\temp\jmeter.zip
  ```
- To unpack JMeter you can use [Expand-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-7.1%5C):

  ```
   Expand-Archive -LiteralPath 'c:\temp\jmeter.zip' -DestinationPath c:\temp
  ```
- To launch JMeter:

  ```
   C:\temp\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\jmeter.bat
  ```

Remember that you will need to have [Java SDK](https://openjdk.java.net/) of version 8+ in order to be able to run JMeter

More information: [Get Started With JMeter: Installation & Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans)

Answer (score 0):

```
$Url = 'https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.4.3.zip'
$ZipFile = 'C:\Users\snehal.khot\Documents\JmeterAndJenkins\Jmeter'+$(Split-Path -Path $Url -Leaf)
$Destination= 'C:\Users\snehal.khot\Documents\JmeterAndJenkins\jmeter'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -OutFile $ZipFile
$ExtractShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$Files = $ExtractShell.Namespace($ZipFile).Items()`
$ExtractShell.NameSpace($Destination).CopyHere($Files)
Start-Process $Destination
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your question to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.