# How to install Taurus and Jmeter in Azure DevOps Pipeline with powershell script?

Tags: azure-devops, jmeter, azure-pipelines, performance-testing, taurus

I am trying to install Taurus and JMeter on Azure DevOps Pipeline with PowerShell/Command line script. Is there any way or command that I can use for running the JMeter In Azure DevOps Pipeline without using Extension?

Note: I don't want to use the extension provided by Azure, I want to download it through custom script.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you sure you need Windows? I'm asking because:

- For getting Taurus you need [Python](https://www.python.org/) and [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/)
- For JMeter you will need [Java runtime](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/)
- For installing Taurus on Windows you will additionally need [Microsoft C++ Build Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504552/how-to-install-visual-c-build-tools) which have immense size and download/installation can take more than 30 minutes

So maybe it worth considering using [Taurus docker image](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-execute-load-test-using-taurus-docker-image) instead?

---

You [have been given instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69526487/2897748) regarding how to install JMeter already, they can be slightly adapted for downloading and installing Python and MSVS Build Tools

Comment: Thanks For the response, The solution(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69526104/how-to-download-and-install-jmeter-using-powershell-task-in-azure-devops/69526487#69526487) that you provided worked Locally. But my main goal is to use Taurus and Jmeter to run the .jmx file in Azure DevOps Pipeline. and I wanted to install these two without using the extension. I want to use any custom command that can be used for installing Taurus, JMeter, and running the .jmx file through the command.